# Abstract Classes v Singletons v Public-statics in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've moved from a functional style of coding Javascript to class based Typescript for work. The are cases where I need only one instance/place for some functionality so sometimes I have gone for an abstract class whilst at other times I have opted for a singleton. My reason for choosing one over the other are a little arbitrary and fuzzy and my colleagues suggestions have sounded fuzzy also.

When would you use an **abstract** class verses and **singleton** class verses a regular class with **public static** methods and properties. Actual examples and use case to help in deciding when to use which would be great.

Currently abstract and singletons seem pretty similar to me when it comes to the case of creating something where there is only **one** but my reason for picking the latter up till now has simply been that I can do `this.property` with a singlton whereas within an abstract it seems correct to use only `abstractClassName.property` which is more verbose. Both seem a good option for centralising state such as a common list of timers item `items[]`

Comment: What is an "abstract class" ? If you mean the Typescript `abstract class` then ... no, this does not sound like a good usecase.

Comment: Since functions are objects, it doesn't really matter (in the JavaScript world). Inside static class methods you can also use `this` to refer to the class itself (again, since functions just objects). In such a case I would simply use an object though (in plain JavaScript at least). I believe abstract classes is a concept from programming languages that don't support direct object creation. *edit:* Uh, I was thinking of *final* abstract classes. Abstract classes itself are useful to be extended by concrete classes...

Comment: @FelixKling on solo projects I agree it doesn't matter but working in a team on an expanding project there needs to be good reasons and consistency for the patterns used, hence the original post. I would like to hear some concrete reasons and possibly see some examples from someone who really understands the topic specifically using **Typescript**

Answer (score 7):

Don't use a class if you don't plan to instantiate it.
Don't use an abstract class if you don't plan to extend it.

A plain object is a better fit for a collection of static methods. In Typescript, you'd probably use a [namespace](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html) or [module](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) of functions.

Comment: `Don't use a class if you don't plan to instantiate it.` a singleton makes one instance and sometime I favour this over abstracts because I can refer to it's internals with `this`, you can do this with abstracts too but I don't think it's semantically corrects as there is no instance.`Don't use an abstract class if you don't plan to extend it` in practice abstract classes are sometimes used to hold a collection of methods to form utility classes. So this assertion doesn't hold up.

Comment: @timebandit: Bergi's point is: `const instance = {foo() { console.log(this); } bar() { this.foo(); }}` also creates an "instance", without the need for a class. That's the advantage of JavaScript. If you have methods that don't need to share state, use a module instead.

Comment: @FelixKling totally agree with you I should qualify my question by saying that i am interested in an object oriented solution that people form a java c# background moving to TS would understand

Comment: @timebandit Well for people coming from java everything has to be a `class` of course… Or you educate them that JavaScript works different, it's object-based not class-based. Using object literals for your singletons with utility methods is the object-oriented JS way.

Comment: @timebandit: Since there are many differences between c#/java and JavaScript classes, knowledge cannot really be transferred IMO. If they have to learn how JavaScript classes work anyway, they might as well learn about how objects work in JavaScript and use them accordingly *shrug*.